# Combining data from multiple sources in one column

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have a tables like

```
    create table dbo.A
    (
        Id int identity(1,1) not null,
        BId int null,
        CId int null,
        SomeData nvarchar(50),
        constraint [PK_A] primary key clustered ([Id] asc),
        constraint [FK_A_B] foreign key (BId) references [dbo].[B]([Id]),
        constraint [FK_A_C] foreign key (CId) references [dbo].[C]([Id]),
    )
    go

    create table dbo.B
    (
        Id int identity(1,1) not null,
        constraint [PK_B] primary key clustered ([Id] asc)
    )
    go


    create table dbo.C
    (
        Id int identity(1,1) not null,
        BId int null,
        constraint [PK_C] primary key clustered ([Id] asc),
        constraint [FK_C_B] foreign key (BId) references [dbo].[B]([Id]),
    )
    go
```

I would like to get back data that would have following in row: 
A.Id, C.Id, A.SomeData where C.Id could be coming either from A.CId directly or as C.Id if you join A to by C on A.BId = C.BId. So let's say in my tables I have following data:

```
    B
    1 
    2

    C 
    1 1
    2 1
    3 2
    4 2

    A
    1 1 3 'test1'
```

Sample SQL to insert test data:

```
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON
    go

    insert B(Id)
        select 1
                union all
        select 2;

    insert C(Id, BId)
        select 1, 1
            union all
        select 2, 1
            union all
        select 3, 2
            union all
        select 4, 2;

    insert A(Id, BId, CId, SomeData)
        values(1, 1, 3, 'test1');
    go

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF
    go
```

What I would like to get back is:

```
    1 1 'test1'
    1 2 'test1'
    1 3 'test1'
```

Comment: Can you add sample data? I wouldn't want to make stuff up and have it not fit your scenario.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik I added sql to insert the test data

Comment: Your description says `B.CId` but there is no such column.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ corrected the question. Basically you can join A to C either directly by A.Cid = C.Id or A.BId = C.Bid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want a `UNION`:

```
SELECT id AS aid,  cid,  somedata 
FROM a

UNION -- ALL

SELECT a.id,  c.id,  a.somedata
FROM a JOIN c ON a.bid = c.bid ;
```

It's not clear if you want a `UNION DISTINCT` or `UNION ALL`. If it's the first, you could combine the subqueries into one, using `OR`. That may produce different plan though, which may be less efficient:

```
SELECT a.id AS aid,  c.id AS cid,  a.somedata
FROM a JOIN c ON a.bid = c.bid 
              OR a.cid = c.id ;
```

Comment: Looks like that was too long day. Completely forgot about unions even usually I use them quite often.